# "Build" item in Windows Explorer's context menu of a VS solution file?

Tags: visual-studio, contextmenu, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I wonder why this is not integrated by default. I'd like to have an item in Windows Explorer's file context menu of a VS solution file to build it.

Is there a tool for this? Or do I have to create this myself?

Comment: Neat idea, but why would you ever need it?

Comment: Because it is faster than opening the solution and hitting F6. Especially if you have a couple of solutions that need to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MSBuild Shell Extension have been there for years,

http://msbuildshellex.codeplex.com/

But you might also try out my new project,

http://msbuildlaunchpad.codeplex.com/releases/view/45368

It is quite easy to use.
[MSBuild Launch Pad http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=msbuildlaunchpad&DownloadId=122261](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=msbuildlaunchpad&DownloadId=122261)

Comment: MSBuildShellExtension has been revived and v2.0 has been released. http://msbuildshellex.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, it is revived. But you can still find something unique in mPad.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be fairly high maintenance, but not impossible.  Open Regedit.exe and locate the HKCR\VisualStudio.csproj.9.0 key.  Add the Build verb, make it look similar to this:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.csproj.9.0\shell\Build]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.csproj.9.0\shell\Build\Command]
@="cmd.exe /k c:\temp\build.bat %1"

The cmd.exe /k command opens a console window so that you can read any error message from the build.  The c:\temp\build.bat file ought to look similar to this:

```
call "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
msbuild %1
```

You probably also want to add the Build key to HKCR\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln so you can build solutions as well.  That however is a bit of a version maintenance headache.

Comment: A possible solution for the version maintenance headache is to write your own launcher who automatically parses the csproj/sln/... files, and then locate the correct msbuild to use. This is what I want to achieve in MSBuild Launch Pad.

Comment: For any poor sap trying to do this in Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 10 watch out for the override in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.sln` (described here https://superuser.com/questions/1424724/file-extension-shell-verbs-dont-show-up-in-windows-10-context-menus) this will override the ability to add an additional option to the context menu UNTIL you delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a project to do it for VS 2003 & 2005.  It could easily be altered for 20080 and 2010 too i imagine.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/VS_BuildHere.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to cook up something using `MSBuild.exe` along the lines of

```
<path_to_msbuild_executable>\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration="<config>" %1
```

However, you would have to specify a configuration and then it will be hard to see all the output from the build. I'm not sure this would make all that much sense.

Comment: Additionally, I'd have to put this in the right place in the registry. I barely remember that this is easy, but it's a hassle nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection of registry entries at http://www.nerdpad.com/windows/msbuild-context-menu-build-net-projectsolution-from-explorer that does this.